# Slow performance but fast WI-FI speeds

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-speed

I’ve got a pretty quick connection (a speed test just showed about 140MBPs download and 40 upload, which is typical across my devices and around my house), though my wife and I frequently get poor connection errors on various video call applications, even when it’s just one of us and nothing else is online. We’ve got an aging AirPort Extreme (maybe ten years old) that seems to be working just fine, but I’m wondering if there might be some sluggishness caused there during higher network usage that doesn’t really show up in the speed tests. Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. Make sure your access point is secured. Change passwords and use a complex one! Are you sure no neighbor is using your connection?

Comment: Hi. Yes it’s secure and I can see that no neighbors or anyone else has been on it.